# Footer location issue with github

Tags: html, css, github, footer, github-pages

I am new to all things programming. So what I have here is a display issue. When I use the active browser directly from vscode, the footer of my site displays in its proper place at the bottom. However, when I open this same site on github pages my footer now hovers about two inches above the viewport bottom.

From vscode:
[footer at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjekp.png)

From github pages:
[floating footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRY4R.png)

Anyone know what I should do here? Thanks!

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #0a1612;
  border-top: 7px solid #1A2930;
  font-size: 1em
}
```

```html
<footer>
  &copy; Copyright 2019 King Major
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you comfortable posting a link to the github page? That way we can troubleshoot the real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `position: absolute`, the footer becomes relative to its parent, so when you specify `bottom: 0` it is pushed down to parent's bottom and since parent's height is not explicitly specified by you, browser will calculate it (which will be less than 100% since your content is short).

So to fix this issue, I'll suggest you set the `min-height: 100%` to the body and html which will fix the issue.

```
body, html {
  min-height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Just looking back at the css and I realized how bad this was.  This was literally the first project in our bootcamp.

Comment: Your suggestion made me look at the top of my CSS and I noticed that I needed to remove the code I mentioned below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would you try that ? Thanks...

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #0a1612;
  border-top: 7px solid #1A2930;
  font-size: 1em
}
```

```html
<footer>
  Copyright 2019 King Major
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

could u check this footer? if you like. Thank you

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
       
       var footerHeight = 0,
           footerTop = 0,
           $footer = $("#footer");
           
       positionFooter();
       
       function positionFooter() {
       
                footerHeight = $footer.height();
                footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";
       
               if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: footerTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }
               
       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionFooter)
               .resize(positionFooter)
               
});
```

```css
* { padding:0px; margin:0px;}

/* Footer */
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 3em 0px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 color: #cccccc;
 background-color: #0a1612;
 border-top: 7px solid #1A2930;
 font-size: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>hellooooooo</p>

<footer id="footer">
        &copy; Copyright 2019 King Major
</footer>
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain the pro's of this footer?  Just curious if there is some benefit to using JS to set styling.  I'm absolutely not knocking your suggestion, and not trying to be rude, I just want to learn. Thanks.

Comment: well! it is using jquery for footer while body content's details are short so footer would be a stay at the bottom automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This was my second project ever, and I had:

```css
html {
    position: absolute
}
```

Once I removed that, I resolved the issue.  Thanks everyone for all your patience and help!